# How to access to the content of JTextField inside of Jpanel inside of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I am trying to read the content of a JTextField inside a JPanel in a JFrame from another Java Class in another file.

So in one .java file I have this code:

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public Ventana() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setTitle("Ventana");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel();
        grafica();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    }

    public void panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 50);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        JLabel etiqueta1 = new JLabel("A: ");
        JLabel etiqueta2 = new JLabel("B: ");
        JLabel etiqueta3 = new JLabel("C: ");

        JTextField cuadroTexto1, cuadroTexto2, cuadroTexto3;
        cuadroTexto1 = new JTextField("    ");
        cuadroTexto2 = new JTextField("    ");
        cuadroTexto3 = new JTextField("    ");
        JButton boton = new JButton("Calcular");
        
     
        panel.add(etiqueta1);
        panel.add(cuadroTexto1);

        panel.add(etiqueta2);
        panel.add(cuadroTexto2);

        panel.add(etiqueta3);
        panel.add(cuadroTexto3);

        panel.add(boton);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.validate();
    }
// more code under...
```

And in another .java file I am trying:

```
public class Controlador implements ActionListener{
    
    private Ventana vista;
    private Datos modelo;
    
    public Controlador( Ventana vista , Datos modelo){
        this.vista = vista;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        
    }
    
     //Inicia los valores del jFrame Ventana con los datos del MODELO "Datos".
    public void iniciar_vista(){
        vista.setTitle( "Demo" );
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        modelo.setA( Integer.valueOf( vista.cuadroTexto1.getText() ) );
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is in the last line of this code to access to "cuadroTexto1", read the consent to send it to another variable but I don't know how to do it.

I am not sure if you have all info you need to provide an answer. If that's the case I will answer any question you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare cuadroTexto1 before the constructor

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JTextField cuadroTexto1; //declaration 
public Ventana() {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setTitle("Ventana");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel();
    grafica();
```

you may also need to add a getter for cuadroTexto1 depending on where is the cuadroTexto1 java file